# PHP - ASCII special characters (without MySQL)

Tags: php, character-encoding

I am doing this PHP page that have access to a Google account and than shows all emails. I've defined a header = UTF-8 and meta too, I used a lot of PHP function to convert the output to UTF but I keep getting strange icons instead of ASCII special characters. Such as `ç`, `é` or `ã`.

```
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset: UTF-8");
    $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);
    echo $message;
```

What should be the output:

```
çççç
```

What I get:

```
=E7=E7=E7=E7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`imap_qprint`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-qprint.php) (see first comment on that page for an alternative solution).

Comment: I used the first comment 's solution an that did it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue, regarding the first comment on the [imap_fetchbody PHP doc page](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imap-fetchbody.php).

Use [imap_qprint](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-qprint.php) or use the commenter solution :

```
<?php
function ReplaceImap($txt) {
  $carimap = array("=C3=A9", "=C3=A8", "=C3=AA", "=C3=AB", "=C3=A7", "=C3=A0", "=20", "=C3=80", "=C3=89");
  $carhtml = array("é", "è", "ê", "ë", "ç", "à", "&nbsp;", "À", "É");
  $txt = str_replace($carimap, $carhtml, $txt);

  return $txt;
}

$mbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "login", "pass");
$no = 5; // Mail to show (mail number)

$text = imap_fetchbody($mbox, $no, 1);
$text = imap_utf8($text);
$text = ReplaceImap($text);
$text = nl2br($text);

echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: By reading the comment below I used this:

        $message = preg_replace("/\=([A-F][A-F0-9])/","%$1",$message);
  $message = urldecode($message);
  $message = utf8_encode($message);